# Restriction of concave function to bounded convex set is concave?

Tags: convex

Suppose I have a function that is concave, and has as its domain $R^n$. If I restrict the function to a bounded convex set, say the probability simplex, then the resulting function should still be concave, right?

I am trying to prove that $ \sum_i log\ (X.P_i)$ is concave, where $X$ is a vector in the probability simplex, and $P_i$ are constant vectors with each component being non-negative.

My proof is as follows:

1) $X.P_i$ is a hyperplane and is therefore concave (this will be useful later).

2) Restriction of a concave function to the probability simplex is concave. Therefore $X.P_i$ where $X$ is a vector in the probability simplex, is concave.

3) Page 84, Ch 3 of Convex Optimization by Boyd Vandenberghe states that:
Let $f = h\ o\ g$. $\ f$ is concave if $h$ is concave, $h^E$ is nondecreasing, and $g$ is concave. Where $h^E$ is the extended value extension of $h$. For me, $h = log$ and $g$ is the function defined in 2 above. This shows that $log\ X.P_i$ is concave.

4) Sum of concave functions is concave.

I think the proof is correct as long as point 2 is correct. I'm pretty sure it is, but wanted to verify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly (thanks @whuber for removing an unnecessarily long argument): suppose $f : S \to \mathbb R$ is concave. Then $\forall x, y \in S$ and $\forall \alpha \in [0,1]$
$$
f\left(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y\right) \geq \alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha) f(y).
$$
In particular, for any $D \subseteq S$ we must have $\forall x, y \in D$ and $\forall \alpha \in [0,1]$
$$
f\left(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y\right) \geq \alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha) f(y)
$$
i.e. the restriction of $f$ to $D$ is also concave. The convexity of $D$ is irrelevant so long as $D \subseteq S$.

Comment: I am curious why you felt it worthwhile to approach this in such an elliptical manner.  Isn't the conclusion an *immediate* consequence of the definition of concavity?  That definition concerns all pairs $x,y$ in the domain of $f$. When you restrict its domain, *a fortiori* the condition remains true for all pairs in the restricted domain, *QED*.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the feedback, very good point. I guess I've been studying analytic continuations recently and wanted to think of it in terms of extensions but clearly that wasn't necessary

Comment: Thank you: I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some subtlety.